# Word or phrase to describe bashing one's opponents to make oneself look good

Tags: phrases, expressions, verbs, verb-phrases

Is there a word, phrase or expression that would describe the action of defaming or speaking ill of someone just to raise your own standing or reputation?  I'm looking for something like what you would find in a political debate.  How political opponents often speak ill of each other in order to make themselves look good in comparison.

Comment: Something simple like *attack*?

Comment: Note that an action like *criticize* or *attack* does not carry with it a motive.

Comment: Yeah, that's the difficult part.  Most of the words I can find do not include motive in them.  And it's the motive portion I'm looking for.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can use your opponent as a ["foil"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foil) to effectively burnish your own image. However, no bashing is necessary for that.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I think "foil" has positive connotations. This isn't what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @user405662 Oh, that's interesting, it doesn't have positive connotations for me. I often think of it as the black material placed under a gemstone to make the jewel seem more brilliant.

Comment: 4 answers from 3K+ users, yet not one up-vote....BTW Welcome to English Language & Usage.

Answer (score 1):

You would like to express the concept of "defaming or speaking ill of someone just to raise your own standing or reputation."  Generally in the political realm this is called **negative campaigning.**  It's used when a candidate spends more time badmouthing the opponent than bragging about him or herself.  And it would typically include some muckraking.

Here's how [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/negative-campaigning) defines *negative campaigning*:

> political campaigning in which a politician or party focuses on criticizing another politician or party rather than emphasizing their own positive qualities.  *Most voters already are tired of the negative campaigning.*

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is called **character assassination**.

> the slandering of a person usually with the intention of destroying public confidence in that person

[Merriam-Webster]

Another such word is **Muckraking**.

> If you accuse someone of muckraking, you are criticizing them for finding and spreading unpleasant or embarrassing information about someone, especially a public figure.
> [*disapproval*]

*The senator accused opposition leaders of muckraking.*

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/muckraking

Answer (score 1):

Such attacks could be called [**invidious**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/invidious).

> 1a : of an unpleasant or objectionable nature
>
> : *obnoxious invidious remarks*
>
> b : of a kind to cause harm or resentment
>
> *an invidious comparison*
>
> 2 : tending to cause discontent, animosity, or envy
>
> *the invidious task of arbitration*
>
> 3 : envious

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the adjective *self-serving*

1. > Serving one's own interests, especially without concern for the needs or interests of others.
2. > Exhibiting concern solely for one's own interests: a speech full of self-serving comments.

Note that political debate often distinguishes *ad hominem* attacks from debate on differences on issues. Those running for office who critique their opponent’s stand on issues often do so not just for their own benefit, but to inform the public about the choices in an election.

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=self-serving

Comment: I'm not sure that the reason for using ad hominem attacks makes much difference to them: they remain ad hominem and carry the same lack of validity. If they do make a valid point, then they may be rude but are not ad hominem.

Comment: Self-serving does not address the idea of using insults, although it is possible to use them in that way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more or less  informal term that does not explicitly aim at saying that the perperator's intent is to enhance his/her reputation in the eye of the audience, but which implies this underlying process, especially in political debates.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/put-down_1?q=put+down)) **put down** phrasal verb **put somebody  down** (informal) to make somebody look or feel stupid, especially in front of other people

> ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/put-down)) 4. **put down**  phrasal verb
> If someone puts you down, they treat you in an unpleasant way by criticizing you in front of other people or making you appear foolish.

There is a corresponding noun: "*put down*".

Comment: This is a generic word/phrase and the OP could find countless such others looking up a thesaurus. I think the OP is looking for something specific here.

Comment: @user405662 To start a research in a thesaurus you need one of the items that have been collected as being similar, but the OP has none, only a long definition. This term I came up with may not be the most specific, but it is at least fairly near to what has been required.